# obtaning a set from classes

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it possible to get a set by a intersection of 2 (non-set) classes?

I can see it is possible from a set and a class, simply by a set contained in the class. Also, I think that the union/product of two classes can't be a set, because then the inclusion/projection function shows that also the classes are sets.

Am I right?

Comment: Well let $k(1)$ denote the class of all $1$-element sets, and $k(2)$ denote the class of all $2$-element sets. What can you say about $(k(1) \cup \{\{0,1,2\}\}) \cap (k(2) \cup \{\{0,1,2\}\})$ ?

Comment: @user18921: Easier still: $k(1) \cap k(2)$ is a set...

Comment: @NateEldredge, true!

Comment: To see that $k(1)$ and $k(2)$ are indeed proper classes, see this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730974/proving-that-for-any-cardinal-number-there-doesnt-exist-a-set-containing-conta (and other questions listed there among linked questions).

Comment: Here's a cute observation: $\mathrm{Ord}\cap\{\mathcal P(x)\mid x=x\}=\langle 0,1\rangle$.