# Proving that the is no set of all sets with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ elements in ZFC

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ be a cardinal distinct from zero.

How to prove in ZFC that there is not set containing all sets of $n$ elements?

$\textbf{Edit 1.}$

If I suppose that the is such a set that contains all sets of $n$ elements, in particular, for $n = 1$ it is the unitary set of all sets. But that set does not exists in ZFC, so that would be a contradiction?

Comment: for $n=1$ it would not be the unitary set of all sets, but the set of all unitary sets.

Comment: In particular, it would contain the unitary set $\{A\}$, for every set $A$; then, taking the union of such set, you would obtain the set of all sets. So your reasoning seems to be correct.

Comment: @amrsa Incredible how intuitive ideas can lead to these contradictions...

Comment: But the key here is the inexistence of the set of all sets; from there, there can't be many sets such as the one you refer to in the post.

Comment: A few posts which are (at least to some extent) related: 
[Is the isomorphism class of a fixed cardinality a set?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/34098), 
[Why does the set of all singleton sets not exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3815), 
[Class of sets of a given infinite cardinality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/21973), 
[Proving that for any cardinal number, there doesn't exist a set containing containing all sets of that cardinality.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/730974)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris Eagle’s answer is absolutely correct, but I think there’s a different, valuable way of looking at this. Specifically, I think this is best viewed as a special case of a more general tool.  I’ll write it up as a separate answer.

To fix a little terminology and notation, let a “class” denote any collection of sets, and let $V$ denote the class of all sets. I am assuming you’re already familiar with the formal reasons that $V$ is not a set.

There are loads of different sufficient conditions for showing that a class is not a set. Here’s one of my favorites:

**Theorem:** Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a class. If for all sets $S \in V$, there is a an element $C \in \mathcal{C}$ such that $S \in C$, then $\mathcal{C}$ is not a set.

**Proof:** To prove this theorem, recall the axiom of union, which says:
$$\forall F \exists A \forall Y \forall x \big [(x \in Y \wedge Y \in F) \rightarrow x \in A \big ] $$
Suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ is a set. Then we may apply this axiom to $\mathcal{C}$ and find that there is a set $A$ such that for all sets $Y \in \mathcal{C}$ and all $x \in Y$, we have that $x \in A$. By our condition on $\mathcal{C}$, we know that for every set $S$, there is a $C \in \mathcal{C}$ such that $S \in C$. It follows that for every set $S$, we have that $S \in A$. Thus $V \subseteq A$.

Additionally, we have that $A$ is a set, so we have that $A$ is a set containing all sets. Since the formula $x=x$ picks out all sets, it follows by restricted comprehension that $\{x \in A : x = x\} = V$ is a set. But there is no set of all sets. Thus $\mathcal{C}$ could not have been a set to begin with. □

---

This is a quite “general test” for checking if a class is not a set. We may easily apply it to your example.

**Corollary:** For $n > 0$, let $F_n$ denote the class of sets with exactly $n$ elements. $F_n$ is not a set.

**Proof:** There are $n$ distinct sets. Thus for any set $S$, there is a set $T$ such that $S \in T$ and $T$ has exactly $n$ elements. Thus we meet the hypotheses of the theorem. □

Comment: I know there is a huge difference but it is like induction principle: every time a model behaves like the naturals, then the naturals are contained in the model, that is, every time a model behaves like the set of all sets, said set $V$ is contained in the model.

Comment: I am shocked on how a class $V$ which we cannot imagine, we can use to study many of its properties and others classes properties! Thanks @Joe

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_n$ stand for the class of sets with $n$ elements. In case of $n=1$, we can use $A_1\in\{A_1\}\in A_1$ to build an infinite chain of membership relationship, which contradicts well-foundedness.

More generally, we have $$A_n\in\{A_n, \mathcal P(A_n), \mathcal P(\mathcal P(A_n)), \cdots, \mathcal P^{n-1}(A_n)\}\in A_n$$ where $A_n, \mathcal P(A_n), \cdots$ are all distinct due to cardinality.

Comment: Completely insane! For that reason, ZFC set axioms is the greatest foundation of modern mathematics. If this were not the case, mathematics would be full of contradictions!! What do you think about?

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed $n$ let $A_n$ be the collection of all $n$-element sets.  By the Axiom of Replacement if you have any set and any class function defined on that set then the image of the function is again a set.  Thus if you can find a class function defined on $A_n$ whose image is something you already know to be a proper class, then $A_n$ is also a proper class.

In the comments the case $n=1$ was addressed: The class function $F : A_1 \to V$ defined by $F(x) = \bigcup x$ (or, equivalently, $F(\{a\}) = a$) is surjective, and $V$ is not a set, so $A_1$ cannot be a set.

For higher values of $n$ you can do similar kinds of things.  For $n=2$ the function $F : A_2 \to V$ defined by $F(x) = \bigcup x$ is almost surjective - it just misses $\emptyset$.  But you (probably?) already know that $V \setminus \{\emptyset\}$ is also a proper class.  At $n=3$ the same definition is produces a surjection from $A_3$ to $V \setminus (\{\emptyset\} \cup A_1)$, which is again a proper class (because we already saw that $A_1$ is a set!).  And so forth...

Comment: A "proper class" is a collection of sets that is too big to be a set in ZFC, right? If so, I understood the whole idea. The fact that $V \setminus \{\varnothing\}$ is a proper class is kind of similar to having an infinite linearly independent set an removing an element, right?

Comment: You don't need the axiom of replacement for this. See @Joe's answer.